# Can't Get Post $http service angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Somebody can help me.
My service:( Service name:reviewService)

```
this.addFeedback = function (param) {
    return httpService.post('my api', param);
}
```

My controller:

```
$scope.param= {
    ParentId: null, 
    Comment: ''
};

//Reply Button
$scope.Reply= function () {

};
//Submit Reply button on Popup
$scope.Submit = function () {
    reviewService.addFeedback($scope.param).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.IsSuccess) {
            $scope.Array = response.data.Value;
        }
    });
};
```

My Idea:
**ParentId is Id of user's comment (Item)
When click Answer Button to reply User comment. I want get Id of Item clicking, set into ParentId of object. And then show popup, insert reply and submit.
Please help me!

Comment: Please show your error!

Comment: i don't have error. because my function is empty. $scope.Answer = function () {
        
    };  . So i need anyone can help me code in this function like as my Idea

Comment: what's your popup library? I think you need to receive 'parentId' from controller that calls the popup.

Comment: i am using modal popup of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Did you inject the $http into your controller/factory?
For example:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("welcome.htm")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: yes i did. please read my idea. "**ParentId is Id of user's comment (Item) When click Answer Button to reply User comment. I want get Id of Item clicking, set into ParentId of object." this is thing i need. please help . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you :)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, reviewService) {
    $scope.comments = [{ParentId: "1", Comment: "Click me 1"}, {ParentId: "2", Comment: "Click me 2"}];
    $scope.param= {
        ParentId: null, 
        Comment: ''
    };
    
    $scope.addFeedback = function (comment) {
        $scope.param.ParentId = comment.ParentId;
        $scope.param.Comment = comment.Comment;

        //Get the comment Id from UI and pass it into the service
        reviewService.addFeedback($scope.param).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.IsSuccess) {
                $scope.Array = response.data.Value;
            }
        });
    }
});

app.factory('reviewService', function($http){
 var factory = {
     addFeedback: function (feedback) {
         var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
             //we will call $http service here
             //return httpService.post('my api', param);
             
             //mockup data
             console.log(feedback);
             setTimeout(function(){
                 resolve(feedback); 
             }, 1000);
             
         });
         
         return promise;
         
     }
 }
 
 return factory;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-click="addFeedback(comment)">{{comment.Comment}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. When i click on. I have a error with function. > this is link http://prntscr.com/kzng63

Comment: when i set like this $scope.param.ParentId = comment.ParentId;
        $scope.param.Comment = comment.Comment;  one error like ParentId undefined. If array like this: [{id: "1", comment: "Click me 1"}, {id: "2", comment: "Click me 2"}];  . How can i Get the comment Id from UI?